# Linq to SQL data class, use conneciton string from machine.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, machine.config

We have developed many asp.net web applications on our intranet server.
Each has their own connection strings in their own web.configs

We are having to upgrade a lot of servers due to OS end of life, including intranet servers & SQL servers.

What I would like to do is standardize the connection strings in the machine.config

This is fine when doing a new SqlConnection in code using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to get the connection string, it picks up ones from machine.config

Where I'm getting stuck is with Linq to Sql classes, I can only choose connection strings from the local web.config.

Is it possible to use machine.config connection strings with a Linq to Sql data class?